# Things to do during layover at Schiphol

Tags: layovers, amsterdam

I have a three hour layover at Schiphol, and this is my first time visiting Schiphol.
Assuming my incoming flight is at time, what can I do to pass my time there?

Also, I want to keep my self engaged so that I don't fall asleep somewhere.

Comment: To whomever just downvoted this - why?

Comment: Dear Travel.SE users, Please **leave a comment** explaining the downvotes. It's common courtesy and will help the OP improving their question. Be nice.

Comment: A) a three hour layover is very short B) Most airports are horrible at this, Schiphol is no exception, your choice are mostly restaurants and bars C) all the fun (like Behind The Scenes Schiphol) is landside because economically it's not viable to organise anything airside.

Comment: Anytime I'm laid over I like to write my 'thank you' notes from the last place I visited, hosts or contacts or whatever. Then find a place to mail them. If there's a prayer room and time I like to go there also.

Comment: @chx I don't know any other airport with a museum.  In my limited experience (I've only been there a few times), it's a great way to find a moment of peace and stimulation of the intellect and/or senses in the midst of a hectic travel day.   See http://www.amsterdam.info/airport-museum/.

Comment: Has the museum re-opened? Last times I walked past it, it was closed and there were works on the area of the airport. I have tried to google it but do not find a clear 'yes it is open' but also no 'it is closed now'.

Comment: It is going to re-open if it is not yet open yet, good enough, thanks.

Comment: It is soo huge airport with a lot of cafes, shops, rooms, book stores (if I remember correct. I don't know about museum, write here if you find it. Also it is very good wifi there so 3 hours it's not a lot in schiphol if you are not going to leave airport

Comment: http://www.schiphol.nl/Travellers/FoodRelax/AfterPassportControl/Relax/Rijksmuseum1.htm definitely closed. That's why I didn't mention it, sorry. But that's a good place to look, http://www.schiphol.nl/Travellers/FoodRelax/AfterPassportControl/Relax.htm

Comment: Schiphol is precisely like any other large airport of today: ie it is precisely like a middle-upmarket shopping mall.  It is absolutely, totally impossible to tell it apart from any other airport-or-mall. You just have the usual brands of shops (Gap, Hermes, etc) and the usual restaurants. There's absolutely nothing, whatsoever, to do other than walk around and look at the Gap, Hermes etc shops.

Comment: @phoog - there's a good museum/gallery thing at BOM.  I've noticed more and more airports have a sort of "cultural sop" nowadays.